# Geo Location Radius Search Using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch, geolocation

I am developing a job portal , in where end users will search for jobs according to their location and proximity radius . Currently the REST APIs are powered by SLIM and MySQL .
In Jobs table there are latitude and longitude in every row . I have searched for this in here and stumbled upon [Geo Distance search with MySQL](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL) .

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
POW(69.1 * (latitude - $lat), 2) +
POW(69.1 * ($long - $long) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;


Where 

$lat =  User latitude

$long = User longitude
```

Now I have two other issues .

1. If Only MySQL query will be sufficient enough or I have to setup Elastic Search with it ?
2. If there are any library or packages that could help me in this particular problem ?

And If you could suggest anything for the search performance that could be useful .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have gone with below -

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       lat,
       lng,
       ROUND((6371 * acos(
                       cos(radians($lat)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians($lng)) +
                       sin(radians($lat)) * sin(radians(lat)))), (2)) AS distance
FROM jobs
HAVING distance < 50
ORDER BY distance;
```

I have done benchmarking with data and found this slightly faster than Mukesh's answer and 2x better than @jision's answer.

Comment: Why would you not use SPARTIAL indexes for this?? You solution will do a full table scan, which is horrible!

Comment: SPATIAL indexes existed in 5.6, so that is hardly an excuse. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
POW(69.1 * (latitude - $lat), 2) +
POW(69.1 * ($long - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

Where

$lat =  User latitude

$long = User longitude

Comment: Is this query will be enough , or I have to use elastic search in it for fast processing ?

Answer (score 2):

```
You have two option to find job by location 

you required 
1. Search users lat long
2. Job users Posted Lat long (it may be job location or job posted user location from database)
3. Query will be like - 
SELECT zip,Round(((ACOS(SIN('$lat' * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS('$lat' * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(('$lon'-longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515),(2)) AS distance FROM Jobs Having distance <= 30 

Else 
1. You have to call all jobs data in single query.

     foreach($joblist as $job){
        $milesresult = $this->calculateDistance($user_lat,$user_lon,$job['latitude'],$jobr['longitude']);
        $miles = explode("-",$vendor['miles']);
         $vendor_max_miles = $miles[1];
        }

2. PHP function for lat long

      function calculateDistance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

            $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;

            $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));

            $dist = acos($dist);

             $dist = rad2deg($dist);

              $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
            $unit = strtoupper($unit);

            if ($unit == "K") {
              return ($miles * 1.609344);
            } else if ($unit == "N") {
                return ($miles * 0.8684);
              } else {
                  return $miles;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Okey great way ! I have to calculate the distance first and then do simple arithmetic in the query for particular results . btw do u think @jision's answer is simpler ?

Comment: And one other thing , Do I need to implement Elastic Search in it to improve performance, simply it will be good enough ?

Comment: First one is quite similar. if you use having clause with query it will take time to run query. if you use second one it will distribute the load time. Yes sure you implement Elastic Search it will be another option for load and quick result